# What is the difference between a layer and a component?

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, composition

My major development framework is the java spring framework. I have to write service layers, controller layer, dao layer, repository layer and so on. There is thousands of tons of layering. I think component based development approach would become more productive than layering. Spring calls every java beans a component. But I think there should be major difference between component and layer. Generally a layer is passive where a component is active. A component fires events, call life cycle callbacks methods and actively handle a task. On the other hand a layer only gives abstraction. So what is the fundamental difference between a layer and a component?

Answer (score 3):

Concepts of layer and component are different, they don't replace each other. Layer is an abstraction. You abstract the business logic from database interactions, or HTTP endpoint handlers. A layer consists of components. There may be multiple components in a layer.

Let's continue with concrete examples. You have `User` and `Group` entities in your system. You will have necessary endpoint handlers for both, named `UserController` and `GroupController`. These are components and together they form as endpoint handler layer. For business logic, you'll have `UserService` and `GroupService`. These are components and they form as the service layer. Same goes with database layer with `UserRepository` and `GroupRepository` components.

If you mean to use full-stack components, in that case all layers are condensed into the handlers. Which means `UserController` implements everything from getting the request, applying business rules, and accessing the db. This structure is hard to test and hard to maintain. After some point, the code gets very messy and hard to deal with. There will be no unit tests, there will only be integration tests which will test everything. There will be no option to change the database access method, somebody may want to use an in-memory repository implementation for test purposes but this technique does not allow it. All in all, layered architecture may seem complex at first, but it comes handy in the long term.

P.S.: If you mean something other than this by components, please leave a comment, then we can continue to the discussion.

Answer (score 3):

Layers and Componentization are 2 design approaches followed with an intent of architectural concerns.

1. If the architecture/design enforces the need to attain reusability,
   extensibility,  modularity & maintainability kind of features,
   Layers would help you.
2. If your application is not too complex with no scope for
       customizations and extensibility, you may choose to code everything
       in few components.

Ultimately, it is strategic architectural & design need, which normally makes you to orchestrate with Layers & components.